# On Postman when ı send get request to my backend Api ı can get a response but in my app ı only get 401 unauthorizated

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a api and i am using passport.js.When user logged in i give them JWT and set axios default header to token.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
```

Everything work when  i send request on Postman.But doesn't work on my React App.(except my default test route)

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "User works" }));
```

I added cors to my express app.It did not work.

this is my backend route

```
router.get(
  "/getuserclass",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
      .populate("classes", { _id: 1, name: 1 })
      .then(user => res.json(user))
      .catch(() => {
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Not found" });
      });
  }
);
```

and this is my get request

```
axios
      .get("/api/users/getuserclass", {
        withCredentials: true,
        crossdomain: true
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

on React app it gave this error

```
401 unauthorized
```

Comment: Did you check in Chrome console whether the request has all the necessary headers etc? I feel your `axios` is not sending the headers.

Comment: Compare request in chrome developer console for test route(working) and getuserClass route(not working). There should be some difference which should help you out in debugging.

Comment: I can't see any token in header.

Comment: I added my token directly to my request and this works.But i don't know why my axios setting doesn't work.How can set my headers for every request ı send?Btw thank you for your help

Comment: I think you could use something like this: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors, I wont put the token on the global scope because if I understood correctly the user logs in and then with the `JWT` you send the request to the server. Hope this helps, cheers sigfried.

Comment: I created instance.Then changed this `axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;` to this `instance.defaults.headers.Authorization = token`.It works now thank you everyone.